# Why datalist does not work when I make it dynamic (Angular 7)?

Tags: angular

I created a function in my .ts file that allows to update a array (empty by default) that I use to create the options of my datalist.

When I inspect the HTML code I see the options in the datalist but they do not show in the GUI

```html
<input list='id-RPG' type="text" pInputText class="inputTextStyle" [(ngModel)]="MyModal" (input)="searchList($event.target.value)"/>
<datalist id='id-RPG'>
 <option *ngFor="let element of array" [(value)]="element ">{{element }}</option>
</datalist>
```

```
ngOnInit(){
this.array = [];
}

searchList(){
//Rest Here
this.array = ["aaa","aab","aac","aad"]
}
```

No error message is displayed

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of that issue.

Comment: Pulled the code to stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8skxmw
I don't see a problem. Your list is empty initially & when you bind to input it adds the contents as array is updated. @Maryannah FYR above link has code, but just not able to reproduce :)

I've just modified

Comment: @knomdlo that's the point, the OP should provide a reproductible example of the issue. I could have done it too, but I'm not the one that knows the issue. And usually, just by providing the [mcve], one can resolve his issue without having to ask a question on SOF (happened to me more than once)

Comment: I think it's enough
I have a datalist in my html code
and an array in my .ts file that allows it to feed it
when I fill my array with data, and i inspect HTML code I see that the options are added in the datalist but they are not showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not possible to update the DataList in real time, every time you have to click outside to get the new data ...
I used the old method, I think it's the right way to do this.

```
<div class="suggestedList" *ngIf="array.length > 0">
 <ul class="UlSugList" *ngFor="let element of array">
  <li class="LiSugList">
   <a (click)="select(element)">{{element}}</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

```
select(RPG) {
    this.MyModal = RPG;
    this.array = [];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've writen [(value)] what don't work. You should write (value)

```
<option *ngFor="let element of array" (value)="element ">
```

And you don't need to initialize array in ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.array = [];
}
```

Just write it as a global variable

```
array: Array<string> = [];
ngOnInit(){}
```